# Разрешить добавочный/необязательный слеш

Tags: php, slim

При указании любого из методов, необходимо что бы у пользователя был доступ к адресу как со слешем в конце, так и без него. Какой паттерн необходимо для этого использовать?

```
$this->get('/some.method/add', // тут необходим паттерн для работы как со слешем, так и без него.
    function(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
    {
        // ...
    }
);
```

Comment: `/add[/]` или `/add/?` не работает?

Comment: @teran: Оу, 1й работает, Запишите как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно [документации (Optional segments)](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html)

> To make a section optional, simply wrap in square brackets:

оциональный сегмент следует заключить в квадратные скобки, таким образом маршрут становится `/add[/]`.

Так же для реализации данной задачи на глобальном уровне для всех маршрутов есть следующая статья [Trailing / in route patterns](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/route-patterns.html)
Которая велит поступить следующим образом

```
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $path = $uri->getPath();
    if ($path != '/' && substr($path, -1) == '/') {
        // permanently redirect paths with a trailing slash
        // to their non-trailing counterpart
        $uri = $uri->withPath(substr($path, 0, -1));

        if($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {
            return $response->withRedirect((string)$uri, 301);
        }
        else {
            return $next($request->withUri($uri), $response);
        }
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
});
```